# Content-Aware Image Cropping with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, image, image-processing

I am working on a CMS like project which users can upload images with contents. I have to create thumbnails for the uploaded images on the fly. Lets say the thumbnail size as 125x75

I can resize images without problem but when it comes to crop operation several problems occur. My resize and crop procedure works like this:

1. Load the original image.
2. Resize the image to desired size preventing the original aspect ratio depending on the given maximum width or height
3. If the result image has a different aspect ration than the output aspect ratio than a centered crop operation is applied.

But what I want to achive is a content-aware cropping as described in Jue Wang's article [Opticrop: Content-aware Cropping with PHP and ImageMagick](http://jueseph.com/2010/06/opticrop-content-aware-cropping-with-php-and-imagemagick/)

Is there any way to do it with C# or is there a library that can do this operation.

Note: I do not want content-aware resizing. Content-aware resizing (seam craving) can be done with ImageResizing.net [SeamCarving plugin](http://imageresizing.net/plugins/seamcarving)

Comment: You actually ask for this function `function opticrop($image, $w, $h, $out, $format)` ported on asp.net, or with other words, a function to determines the center-of-edginess, and crop the image around there.

Comment: Yes. That is what I am exactly looking for. I have to find the the center-of-edginess as you have mentioned but how? I think I have to port it myself.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the ImageResizing.net framework, the [WhitespaceTrimmer plugin](http://imageresizing.net/plugins/whitespacetrimmer) may be a good starting point I think.

If you want to write the code yourself, [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/a54cd41137b678935c91) shows a good solution using entropy but is written in Ruby.

Comment: Well, actually I can't figure out how WhitespaceTrimmer plugin will help me to find the center-of-edginess as Aristos commented on my post. I do not have any problem with white space.

Comment: The WhitespaceTrimmer plugin uses edge detection to find parts of the image that has to be removed. As it is open-source, I thought you could have a look there and use that as a starting point...